# Converting Nested List into Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I take a nested List and group it into a tuple of three without importing any module. Please show the expanded for loops so I can understand it better. 
For example, I want this nested List.  Note this will always multiples of 
3 sub lists so there is not a index error.
Thankyou.

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]] # Given

[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)] # Result Wanted
```

Comment: What language are trying to do this in? JavaScript? PHP?

Comment: @dylanjameswagner did you see the Python tags?

Comment: @SportsPlanet please do not edit your question to drastically change what you're asking once you've received answers. Especially don't change the language you are asking about; doing so will invalidate the existing Python answers, which is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @gilch, ohp, no I did not. heh

Answer (score 2):

No need for indexes. You can use `next()` on an iterator even inside a for loop:

```
xss = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
it = iter(xss)
answer = []
for x, in it:
    answer.append((x, next(it)[0], next(it)[0]))
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a way without next(), and iter(xss), maybe a longer way?

Answer (score 0):

You can slice with a step size of 3 and zip to make the triples, do a nested unpacking in the for loop, and rebuild the triples without the wrapping lists.

```
xss = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
it = zip(xss[::3], xss[1::3], xss[2::3])
answer = []
for [x], [y], [z] in it:
    answer.append((x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
given = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]  # because this is a list within a list

output = []

for i in range(0, len(given),3): # step size 3 indicated
    temp = (given[i][0], given[i+1][0], given[i+2][0]) # therefore you need the "[0]" behind each given[i]
    output.append(temp)
print (output)
```